# copiar valores de una tabla o a otra tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo una tabla y en ella una columna llamada referencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito copiar todos los valores de esta columna en otra columna llamada codigo, esta columna esta vacia

el resultado es una copia exacta de la columna referencia

debe quedar asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo este update

```
tep_db_query("update ".TABLE." set codigo = 'referencia'");
```

pero no me funciona no copia nada.

hice este while y tampoco me funciona me copia el utlumo valor me repite en todas columnas el ultimo valor:

```
$copia_ref_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_ . "");
        while ($copia_ref = tep_db_fetch_array($copia_ref_query)) {
            tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . "set cod_anterior = '" . $copia_ref['referencia'] . "'");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en las comillas simples. Tal como lo has puesto el resultado es que la columna Codigo contendrá el valor 'Referencia' y debes apuntar a la columna Referencia, no asignarle el string 'Referencia'

Debería ser así:

```
tep_db_query("update ".TABLE." set codigo = referencia");
```

En el `WHILE`, cuando haces el `UPDATE`, te faltaría el `WHERE` para que actualice la fila que deseas.